# How to isolate component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a problem at the beginning of my Vue education.
I made a small app. How can I isolate component?
After clicking on the arrow I'd like to open only one section of information.
Here's the code and live demo:
https://lemonwm.github.io/app_vue/
https://github.com/lemonWM/app_vue

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible snippet with your code here or on jsfiddle? It's gonna make it easier to debug than reading trough your source code.

Comment: @Phiter here's jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/we4u5k9n/12/

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to iterate through your recipes, you can add a property `expanded: false` for each recipe and toggle this one (instead of a global data property):

```html
<div class="element-menu" v-for="recipe in recipes">
  <div class="main-element">
    <h2>{{ recipe.title }}</h2>
    <div>
      <button v-on:click='recipe.expanded = !recipe.expanded'><img src="img/arrow_06.png" alt=""></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="desribe-element">
    <div v-if='recipe.expanded'>
      <div class="recipe-ingredience-left">
        <h3>Składniki</h3>
        <p v-for="ingredient in recipe.ingredients">{{ ingredient }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="recipe-ingredience-right">
        <h3>Przygotowanie</h3>
        <p>{{ recipe.description }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    recipes: [
      {
        title: "Spaghetti",
        ingredients: [
          "Podwójna porcja makaronu",
          "500g sera białego tłustego",
          "2 łyżeczki soli (lub do smaku)",
          "1/2 łyżeczki zmielonego pieprzu"
        ],
        description: "Lorem...",
        expanded: false //<-- here
      },
      {
        title: "Carbonara",
        ingredients: [
          "...",
        ],
        description: "..",
        expanded: false,
      },
    ] 
  }
}
```